# PutRecordBatch.Requests vs PutRecordBatch.Records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

with AWS Kinesis Firehose, will the difference between the PutRecordBatch.Requests and PutRecordBatch.Records metrics give me Put failures?

i've tried plotting both in cloudwatch, but never saw the two diverge. not saying they couldn't either.

Answer (score 0):

No, the difference of both metrics is not equal to `Put Failures`.

Each `PutRecordBatch` request supports upto 500 records and these records are passed as array of records in the request payload. Hence each request can have one or more records.

Whereas the `PutRecordBatch.Records` measures the total number of records from `PutRecordBatch` operation, that will be most likely always higher than number of requests.

Comment: so what is the best metric for measuring delivery failures from firehose to elasticsearch? is DeliveryToElasticSearch.DeliveryRejected valid?